# IP aliasing preference

Tags: linux, network-interface, ip-address

all.
I have create a virtual interface:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp  

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 192.168.2.40
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I can see with ipconfig the inferfaces

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:75:61:2a  
      inet addr:192.168.2.26  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::cbbf:5f7:74ff:7744/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:702 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1135 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:111672 (109.0 KiB)  TX bytes:165411 (161.5 KiB)

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:75:61:2a  
      inet addr:192.168.2.40  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

I want to know if I can configure that interface 2(eth0:1) only works if interface 1(eth0) has not obtained a DHCP address or could not renew it. And in case the interface 2 (eth0:1) is running if interface 1 (eth0) has a DHCP address,  interface 1 (eth0) has priority and interface 2 (eth0:1) stops working.

Thanks!
Regards!

Comment: `..I can see with ipconfig the inferfaces...`, I believe Linux has `ifconfig` not `ipconfig`